# Using 1 taxonomy for multiple post types?

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy

I previously declared the taxonomy " artist " for a profile post type.

Now i am creating a CD post type and would like to use the same artist list from the profile post type

That is one example if i get a solution i will be using this to share a number of other taxonomies among-st post types :D

Thanks in Advance.

P.S. I use JW Custom Post Types
https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Easy-WordPress-Custom-Post-Types/

Comment: I asked the taxonomy and he said it was ok.

Comment: Please, check the [faq] and the page [ask].

Comment: @Katmassive also mark the correct answer as accepted so it helps people find it easier :)

Answer (score 15):

You can use an array of post types in `register_taxonomy()`

> $object_type (array/string) (required) Name of the object type for the
>   taxonomy object. Object-types can be built-in Post Type or any Custom
>   Post Type that may be registered.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

Example:

```
register_taxonomy( 'artist', array( 'profile', 'cd' ), $args );
```

Comment: I got and undeclared error from the jw_custom_posts im using jw custom post type i probably should have included that https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Easy-WordPress-Custom-Post-Types/

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use [register_taxonomy_for_object_type()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type) to link existing taxonomies to existing post types.